# Analysing Data from a peculiar CSV file in which the values are combined in a single cell

Tags: csv

This is the csv file that I have from one of my clients:

[CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_NO-N-VZuNiRDV2ZnVXZ3FGWHc/view?usp=sharing)

In the file, several values are in a single cell, separated by commas. How could I separate the values to different cells in all the cells except copying and pasting. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You'll need to include (the relevant parts of) a problematic file **in the body of your post** - links to external sites (especially those that hide their content behind a Javascript) don't suit the long-term nature of Stack Overflow.  It would help to have an indication of what you've tried so far (we don't even know which language you're writing in!).

Comment: @TobySpeight The file being a csv file, how could I best include more details, except by sharing a link to the file?

Comment: You could quote a few lines - CSV is plain text, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SPLIT function from Google Docs

[Google Docs SPLIT function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnO72.png)

```
=SPLIT(A4,",")
```

Use it in the cell where you want your first value, the other values will be split in the contiguous cells.

Comment: Thanks. Though the function worked for first four rows, after that I am getting this error:"Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C9." Any hints for that?

Comment: @vidyarthi check it here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nlHpyp_UXrXw7MECMlM8cJYxVkllOUm9U3WFc2k5cw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TobySpeight solution was in the image. I added the code part as text in the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem. Anyways, is there a similar function in excel or libre office calc?

Comment: there is a text to columns wizard in the data menu
Data -> Text to Columns